# Thanking Christian for his prayers

Tags: tefilla, avodah-zarah, christianity

Taking into account that Christianity is Avoda Zara I would like to ask the following question.
I met a missionary last night who started off the conversation saying that he prays for Israel and then subsequently trying to get me to accept the New Testament.

I responded to what he was saying but since I was in a rush and didn't want to end off on bad terms I ended off saying, thank you for your prayers.

Was this wrong as he is praying to an Avoda Zara (Shituf) and I was thanking him for that or could it be viewed that I was thanking him for putting his thoughts with Israel (as I don't value prayers to Avoda Zara)?

Comment: Let's back it up to a more common case ... how about the non-proselytizing Trinitarian friend/neighbor/co-worker who says "I'm praying for you." Can you respond with "thanks" to that?

Comment: Rabbi Nachman said, You should value it very much if when you get a brocho from an goy/akum.. not sure of the lashon probably akum tbh but it's probably Sefer haMidot section Brocho.

Comment: To get back to OP's question, it is worth keeping in mind that the  missionary only said that he prays for Israel to get on your good side. His intentions are to destroy your neshama.

Comment: @NissimNanach Rebbe Nachman also went out of his way to not be a posek though ;)